# How to merge values of two rows into single row for same id?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have data in a table(list) as shown below,

```
 id      no1   no2
 1000    0     511
 1000    820    0
```

I need data like shown below,

```
id      no1    no2
1000    820    511
```

Can anyone solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what specific aggregation option you are thinking ? `MAX`  or `SUM` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum or max:

```
select id,max(no1),max(no2) from tab_name group by id;
```

or

```
select id,sum(no1),sum(no2) from tab_name group by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

simple group by with summation will work for you

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  SUM(NO1) NO1,
  SUM(NO2) NO2
FROM Table1
Group by ID
```